# JavaScript: sort array of objects dynamically given array of fields

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to write a helper function in JavaScript that takes an unsorted array of objects and an array of fields and sorts the array in place based on the given fields. Here's what I have so far:

```
const sortByFieldsInPlace = (arr, fieldNames) => {
  arr.sort((a, b) => {
    for (const field of fieldNames) {
      if (a[field] > b[field]) return 1;
      if (a[field] < b[field]) return -1;
    }
  });
};
```

It seems to work so far:

```
const arr1 = [
  { name: 'A', code: 'D' },
  { name: 'B', code: 'A' },
  { name: 'A', code: 'Z' },
  { name: 'A', code: 'A' },
  { name: 'B', code: 'D' },
  { name: 'B', code: 'B' },
  { name: 'B', code: 'B' }
];
sortByFieldsInPlace(arr1, ['name', 'code'])
console.log(arr1)
// [
//   { name: 'A', code: 'A' },
//   { name: 'A', code: 'D' },
//   { name: 'A', code: 'Z' },
//   { name: 'B', code: 'A' },
//   { name: 'B', code: 'B' },
//   { name: 'B', code: 'B' },
//   { name: 'B', code: 'D' }
// ]

const arr2 = [
  { name: 'A', code: 'D' },
  { name: 'B', code: 'A' },
  { name: 'A', code: 'Z' },
  { name: 'A', code: 'A' },
  { name: 'B', code: 'D' },
  { name: 'B', code: 'B', status: 10 },
  { name: 'B', code: 'B', status: 9 }
];
sortByFieldsInPlace(arr2, ['name', 'code', 'status'])
console.log(arr2)
// [
//   { name: 'A', code: 'A' },
//   { name: 'A', code: 'D' },
//   { name: 'A', code: 'Z' },
//   { name: 'B', code: 'A' },
//   { name: 'B', code: 'B', status: 9 },
//   { name: 'B', code: 'B', status: 10 },
//   { name: 'B', code: 'D' }
// ]
```

Does this look good or does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value). Do look beyond the accepted answer - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4760279/215552) solves the multiple-properties question.

Comment: `String.prototype.localeCompare()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Comment: what is the problem with the code?

Comment: Your approach is clean and simple. Unless you're looking for performance gains, it's ideal IMO. You could potentially replace the 4 line sort predicate with the 2 lines: `let field = fieldNames.find(field => a[field] !== b[field]); return field ? a[field].localeCompare(b[field]) : 0;` But this would only work for string values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution seems good to me, I would add a final "return 0" outside of the for loop to cover the situation where the objects being compared are identical. Other than that I think you have it covered.

Comment: Good call. Also prevents a console log warning saying `Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function`